# Why I can' see new version google apps script editor?

Tags: google-apps-script, ide

I'm in Japan. By now I still just can see the legacy version. Anyone know why?

I googled but got no answer. And there is no button for switch between legacy version and the new version.

Comment: Wait a couple of days and it will appear. Google extended the transition until January

Comment: Also, it seems that the free accounts have the new code editor available before paid accounts.

Answer (score 2):

Updates from [workspace blog](https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2020/12/google-apps-script-ide-better-code-editing.html) say

> Update
> This post has been updated to reflect a change in rollout pace. It is now an extended rollout (longer than 15 days for feature visibility), which we expect to complete in January 2021. We previously stated it would be a gradual rollout (up to 15 days for feature visibility) starting on December 7, 2020.

It is normal for you to not see the button until 31 January 2021.